# Getting file name while reading files from local system using pyspark

Tags: python, xml, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

### Additional update:

I tried writing same code for my files present in hdfs there it is working but when i am using same code for my local files system i am getting error. Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/root/cd/parsed_cd_5.xml does not exist

---

## Original question and initial update

I am using **ElementTree** to parse XML files. I ran the code in python and it worked like charm. But when i am trying to run the same using spark i am getting below error.

**Error:**

> File "/root/sparkCD.py", line 82, in 
>       for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 67, in join
>       elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):

From the error it is clear that issue is with "**for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml'))**". But i don't know how to achieve the same in **pyspark**.
since i can't share my code i will only share the snippet where i am getting error compared to the python code where i am not getting the error.

**Python:**

```
path = '/root/cd'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):

   tree = ET.parse(filename)

   doc = tree.getroot()
```

**Pyspark:**

```
path = sc.textFile("file:///root/cd/")

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):

   tree = ET.parse(filename)

   doc = tree.getroot()
```

how can i resolve this issue. All i want is the filename that i am currently processing that is currently in my local system **cd** directory using pyspark.
Forgive me if this sounds stupid to you.

**Update:**

I tried the suggestion given below but i am not getting the file name.
below is my code:

```
filenme = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///root/cd/")
nameoffile = filenme.map(lambda (name, text): name.split("/").takeRight(1)(0)).take(0)
print (nameoffile)
```

result i am gettng is

> PythonRDD[22] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43

**Update:**
 I have written below code instead of **wholeTextFiles** but i am getting same error. Also i want to say that according to my question i want to get the name of my file so textFile will not help me with that. I tried running the code you suggested but same result i am getting.

```
path = sc.textFile("file:///root/cd/")

print (path)
```

Comment: if I understood your problem correctly then `sc.wholeTextFiles('<path>') ` would help. it returns pairRDD where key will be absolute file path and value will be entire file content as string.

Comment: `PythonRDD[22] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43` is expected as you are trying to print rdd. use rdd.collect or foreach to print rdd content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input directory contains many small files then wholeTextFiles would help, check detailed description [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles).

```
>>pairRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles('<path>') 
>>pairRDD.map(lambda x:x[0]).collect()  #print all file names
```

pairRDD each record contains key as absolute file path and value as entire file content.

Comment: I have a directory whose size is close to 7 GB but the individual files inside are of size 500 kb to 1Mb, can i use `wholeTextFiles` there ?

Comment: How can i extract the filename using `wholeTextFiles` ? can you please provide some sample ?

Comment: I have updated answer i would strongly suggest you to go through RDD transformation and aggregation  function on spark wiki.

Comment: i tried writing same code for my files present in hdfs there it is working but when i am using same code for my local files system i am getting error. `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/root/cd/parsed_cd_5.xml does not exist`

Comment: @Ironman you can use only python specific APIs to read files in local instead of spark python api.

Comment: I am following what you said and almost there to achieve it. I am now facing the issue to get the file name of the current file that is being processed. How can i extract the current file path,that is being processed as i am getting all the files name in the list. How can i do this.

Comment: i tried using `.collect()` and then tried to read the file locally but it didn't worked as it is expecting the files to be present in all nodes. Help me out

Comment: "locally but it didn't worked as it is expecting the files to be present in all nodes"--there are no separate nodes in local mode. I feel you need to read first about spark fundamentals, all such issues would be resolved once you read spark wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but this appears to be a clear problem with your code.

In python you have:

```
path = '/root/cd'
```

Now path should contain the location that you are interested in.

In pySpark however, you do this:

```
path = sc.textFile("file:///root/cd/")
```

Now path contains **the text in the file at** the location that you are interested in.

If you try to run your followup command on that, it makes sense that it tries to do something strange (and thus fails).

Comment: i tried your way but still getting the same result.

Comment: @Ironman Please update your question to show exactly what you tried. (Specifically, is there any difference between your python and pyspark code, and have you tried just running the python code?).

Comment: i have updated my question. Please check i want the name of the file as i mentioned. Can you give me any proper working example. It would really help me.

Comment: i tried writing same code for my files present in hdfs there it is working but when i am using same code for my local files system i am getting error. Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/root/cd/parsed_cd_5.xml does not exist can you suggest something

Comment: how can i iterate through the filenames i am getting in `wholeTextFiles`. I wan to get the current file path. Please help.